# Is there any road you can walk on as a pedestrian to get between the Columbus Airport (CMH) and the nearby hotel area?

Tags: airport-transfer, walking, cmh

I'm flying to John Glenn Columbus International Airport (CMH) and arriving at nighttime (23:30). As I need to travel another two ours or so to get to my final destination, I'm thinking of staying at one of the hotels located around half a kilometre from the airport terminal, to then walk back and catch a bus departing from outside the airport terminal to my final destination.

This sounds like it would be walking distance, but looking at the map I only spot roads that look designed for cars and no pedestrian walkways. Consulting Google Maps' navigation tool, it told me to walk down the spiral that leads up to the car parking garage, which doesn't really sound like a good idea to me given that it looks to be designed for cars rather than people, so I'm not sure I'd be allowed to walk there even. There is a free bus I could take to transfer this distance (bus line 7 from Airport Baggage Claim to International Gateway & Sawyer Rd), but it looks like it doesn't operate at the time I arrive — according to Google Maps, the last one for the day departs from Airport Baggage Claim at 23:03 and after that there are none until 5:28 the next day. As my plane arrives 23:30, this is unfortunately not an option as far as I can tell.

Given this, it seems like my only real option apart from getting a taxi (which feels very silly given the short distance) is walking, but is this possible to do in a safe manner which won't get me arrested at this airport?

Comment: Being arrested is still less bad than being killed by a car because the driver did not expect you there.

Comment: @Willeke Absolutely. My intent was that "safe manner" would imply not getting run over, but I now realise that it could be interpreted ambiguously as safe from getting arrested.

Comment: Google says its walkable (and is right about this more often than not). Most airport hotels operate a shuttle (check website). You can also just call the hotel and ask.

Comment: According to the [Columbus Airport website](https://flycolumbus.com/at-the-airport/airport-hotels), many of the hotels right by the airport also operate shuttles for their guests, many of them 24 hours per day. You could call the hotel you are considering staying at to ask about their specific procedures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the satellite view, there is a sidewalk (with marked crosswalks) along the north side of the loop road coming out from the terminal, going past the "walking lot" parking, and then curving up to near the sidewalk in front of Fairfield Inn & Suites. (And Fairfield Inn & Suites is also connected by parking lots to Hampton Inn, Hilton Garden Inn, and Residence Inn; although there isn't an explicit sidewalk or walkway, it is relatively safe to walk in a parking lot.)

Comment: Baggage claim is on the ground level, so just turn right when you get outside. There is a sidewalk all the way to the parking lots of the hotels, and sidewalks ring the parking lots. (I live about 10 minutes away and picked up someone a few weeks ago.